# Waiting time in an immigration-birth process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Could someone please verify that none of the four given choices are correct? Isn't the correct answer $$\frac 1{(\lambda + 4\beta)^2} + \frac 1{(\lambda + 5\beta)^2} + ... +\frac 1{(\lambda + (3+n)\beta)^2}?$$

[image]

Comment: Yes. And yes. (What is the source?)

Comment: ..excerpted from class quiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And yes. (And some irrelevant words.)

Comment: MSE answers must have at least 30 characters.